# "Can't start launcher" message on Xiaomi devices

Tags: java, android

I have an application which pins shortcuts to Android home screen. I'm using `Intent` and `ShortcutManager` API to pin shortcuts for devices with Android 7.1.2 and below and for Android 8.0 and above respectively.

Everything worked fine until Xiaomi released MIUI 9. I tested my app on stock Android and on a Samsung one and it worked fine. It worked fine even with MIUI 8. Let me describe the issue I'm facing in MIUI 9.

In MIUI 9, the shortcut is pinned to Home Screen successfully and there's no issue till this step. But when I try to open the shortcut, it says **Can't start launcher**. This error most probably means that OS couldn't find an app to open the file. But there's an inbuilt PDF reader in all the devices I tested. I even installed Adobe Reader and a couple of other PDF readers and still, it didn't work. Here's the culprit code:

```
private void addShortcut(String path1, String pdfName) {
        File file = new File(path1);
        if (file.exists()) {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            shortcutIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            Intent addIntent = new Intent();
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, pdfName);
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                    Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this.getApplicationContext(),image));
            addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Some error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Since the code is working fine on Stock Android and many custom skins, I assume it's not the issue with my code. It's there something with MIUI 9. I have explored the whole web but there's no documentation or something related to this issue on Xiaomi's website or any other.

I have done lots of debugging and found out:

- When I don't set a data-type in the code and opens the shortcut, it asks me for an app to open the shortcut. Then I choose, for example, "Adobe Reader" and it still doesn't work. Adobe Reader opens but doesn't open the file. I get a toolbar with title "Adobe Reader" and white screen below that. Unable to understand this behavior
- Tried changing the data-type to something like `application/*` and still no benefit.

If anyone wants to try and debug the app, here's the repo: https://github.com/sidhuparas/PDFPinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an OS bug itself and is fixed in MIUI 9 running on Android Oreo. Note that not all MIUI 9 run on Oreo. The ones running Nougat had the bug.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have a device like this lying around, I can only suggest running `adb shell dumpsys package` and digging around in its output. In there you should look for the Activity Resolver Table section. It lists the types schemes, and actions accepted by the packages. It should give you an insight into what you can send in an intent and what you can't.

Answer (score 0):

in dualapps sttings, delete the dualapp accounts.
Phone will reboot.
afterwords, you can creat dual apps and you should be fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).